How to read these Chinese ancient writings below? (Characters identified: 承坭齋)
This is the pot with markings:


承 chéng 
坭 ní 
齋 zhāi
It is the company that produces this ceramic. The name means “company supporting 坭兴陶”, where 坭兴陶 is a specific kind of ceramic originated from Qinzhou. The ceramic and the company is mentioned in this news article (zh-CN).
